# Env Variable Array

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to have array as environmental variable in deployment?

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: array-deployment
  namespace: array-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: array-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: array-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: array-deployment
        image: array-deployment:beta
        env:
        - name: ENV_PROJECTS
          value: "project1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
```

For an example, I want to have an array of projects for `ENV_PROJECT`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Environment variables are plain strings and do not support arrays as input

In order to achieve what you want, you would want to pass the values as a comma separated list. (You might want to use some other separator if your data contains `,`)

so your yaml manifest would become

```
    - name: ENV_PROJECTS
      value: "project1,project2"
```

This assumes that your code in the image `array-deployment:beta` supports reading comma separated values from the env var

Comment: Thanks, that's is what I was after, a confirmation :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but I would like to add some additional information, since search engines landed me here when I was searching for this.

Check the documentation for your application framework to see if they support some environment variable format that will convert into an array.

For example, in .NET Core, setting these ENVs in your deployment YAML

```
- name: "Projects__0"
  - value: "project1"
- name: "Projects__1"
  - value: "project2"
```

will serialize to this JSON which can be used alongside appsettings.json

```
{
    "Projects": ["project1", "project2"]
}
```

This Stackoverflow answer explains a similar concept in the Spring Boot framework: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75936733/9983227

So to reiterate: environment variables must be of type `string`, but your framework may have some environment variable notation you can use so that your code can treat the configuration as an array.