# How to specify arrays and maps in kubernetes service yaml spec?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to send my kubernetes spec a list. My yaml looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  env:
    - name: ENV1
      value: http://someurl.com
    - name: ENV2
      value: val2

    - name: AN_ENV_LIST
      value:
        - val2
        - val3
```

But of course I get an error:

```
invalid type for v1.Application.spec.env.value: got "array", expected "string"
```

My question is, is this even possible with kubernetes?

How do I specify a list?

And a bonus question - what about maps? Is that possible?

Comment: no You can not, it accepts string. if You want to do something like that, just pass it as string and in your container handle it within your code or using an external tool like `yq`. so set your `value: '[ "val2", "val3"]'` and in container do `echo "${AN_ENV_LIST}"  | yq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are of type `string`, so you cannot pass an array in a single variable.

You can either encode the array to be a string, but the application must be aware of that encoding. Alternatively pass multiple *environment variables*, if the application supports that.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, kubernetes only supports environment variables which are strings.

But there are ways about this with some Spring boot magic:

In your kubernetes shifter-patch.yaml:

```
  - name: WHITELISTED_APPS
  value: app1, app2, app3
```

Now in your application spring boot configuration, just read whitelistedApps as a List (or array)

Maps are also possible:

For this example I am placing placeholders in a Spring flyway configuration.

Flyway.placeholders is a Map<String, String>

My normal Spring boot application config would look like this:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    placeholders:
      appuser0: user0
      appuser1: user1
```

But in my kubernetes shifter-patch.yaml I can inject these as:

```
  - name: SPRING_FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_APPUSER0
  value: user0
  - name: SPRING_FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_APPUSER1
  value: user1
```

Hope this is useful to others out there using Kubenetes and Spring boot apps.